# How can I use a custom work item when creating a "Bug" from a test failure in Azure Devops Server?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

#### Background

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2020 at our company.
(*Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1*, installed [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-202011-patch-4-release-date-january-26-2022))

We are using the XML process workflow with customized workitems, as well as a yaml pipeline configuration that runs about 100k tests.

Sometimes tests prove flaky. We previously used teamcity where you can simply mark a test flaky and people would recognize that. [In DevOps, it is not possible yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/flaky-test-management?view=azure-devops). I have checked the settings page and the *Test management* section is not there.

Instead, we have resorted to the use of Bugs to assign a flaky test to a team that will fix it:

**Screenshot**:
[Test failure with the option to create a bug for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiZEO.png)

It does however clutter/skew our bug statistics. Ideally, we would like to use Bug workitem for problems reported by humans, not test failures.

#### What I have tried

What I have tried is to create a different work item type `Test Issue` in the `Microsoft.BugCategory` with the intent for it to be used when a test has failed:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cat:CATEGORIES xmlns:cat="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/categories">
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.BugCategory" name="Bug Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Test Issue" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" name="Requirement Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Robot Story" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="API Request" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Proposal" />
  </CATEGORY>
  [. . .]
```

The line of interest is this one: `<WORKITEMTYPE name="Test Issue" />`

However, this did not make `Test Issue` appear under the test result's "Create Bug" button.

#### Questions

Is there a way to configure the button in the screenshot to present more options than simply *Create bug*?

Is it possible to hack the installation to use a different work item than *Bug* to be created when using the *Create bug* button?